# TIKZ externalize no longer works on MiKTeX

Tags: tikz-external, externalize

Perhaps after the most recent update to win10, running TiKZ externalize command in TeXWorks gives the error message that the shell command is missing (it is not, and externalization worked recently).  The error message in the log file for the missing figure contains the following:

> LaTeX Error: Index type `default' undefined.

and ends with

```
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!

The log file for the master document contains the following:

 (BoS.tex
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-o
n-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "epistemics-figure0" "\def\tikzexternal
realjob{epistemics}\input{epistemics}"' ========
\openout3 = `epistemics.auxlock'.

runsystem(pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname
 "epistemics-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{epistemics}\input{epistemics}")
...executed.

\openout3 = `epistemics.auxlock'.


! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "epistemics-figure0" "\d
```

And finally, the file epistemics.auxlock contains one line:

```
\def \tikzexternallocked {0}
```

I am completely mystified.   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You should make a small, complete example that can be used for tests.

Comment: In trying to create a simple example, the problem disappeared.  It only appears in the complete document.  I am puzzled, since externalize used to work in the complete document.

Comment: then you will have to find the point in your complete document where it breaks.

Comment: I have figured out that the problem is the following comand in the preamble: 
 \newcommand{\emphi}[1]{\emph{#1}\index{#1}}

Comment: Any ideas why this in the preamble and then using this would cause a problem?

Comment: Well, if the command is indeed the cause of the problems, you will for sure be able to use it to provide a small document that illustrates the issue. (Note that I am not saying that there cannot be an interference with the index, but the burden of proof is on your side IMHO.)

Comment: Sorry, i meant to send the file last night. Following illustrates the issue.  Deleting \emphi and externalization works.  Deleting \externalize and file compiles OK.                  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\emphi}[1]{\emph{#1}\index{#1}}   
\usetikzlibrary{external}   
\tikzexternalize
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (1,9) --  (3,7.5) ; 
\draw [->] (1,9) -- node [left]{Out} (-1,7.5) node[below]{$2,2$} ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\emphi{extensive form rationalizability} 
\end{document}